# RewriteRule not working on new server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule but for some reason it's not working...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^grants/$ /grants/index.php
RewriteRule ^grants/([a-zA-Z0-9,_-]+)/$ /grants/index.php?action=$1 [QSA]
```

I have a grants folder locally in httpdocs, in the grants folder I have an index.php and the name of the file being requested so for example, grants/dashboard = grants/index.php?action=dashboard

But for some reason this isn't working.  It was was working on my old server but I have migrated to a new one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, solved now.  Added

```
Options -MultiViews
```